# Madge and relative path not working on windows

Tags: node.js, filepath, madge

I am trying to run the following cmd on windows 11:
`madge --circular src/**/**.ts`

I am getting this error:
`Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Users\Basti\Documents\GitHub\repo\src\**\**.ts'`

when trying to run the command with an absolute path like
`madge --circular src/services/index.ts`
it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Try this `src/**/*.ts` the error is double `**`

Comment: Didnt work, already tried but thanks anyways

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).